# Record two set of point location from mouse event from first frame of a video

Tags: python, opencv

I have a video of the cow farm. My objectives are -

(a) get the location of the corners of the cow pen (cowhouse)

(b) get the corners of the food container

Here is my approach I am thinking about-

```
(a)  - capture the frame and freeze on the 1st frame

     - user will manually put the mouse on the corners

     - the x,y location will be saved in a list

     - press "p" key to proceed to the next frame


(b)  - freeze the frame on the second frame

     - user will manually put the mouse on the corners

     - the x,y location will be saved in another list

     - press "c" key to proceed to next frames
```

I already have other codes to carry out other operations. I tried the following codes to get point from an image (not video). Now sure how to pause the video and use the existing frame as the input image

```
import cv2, numpy as np

ix,iy = -1,-1
# the list of locations
mouse = []
def get_location(event,x,y,flags,param):
    global ix,iy
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDBLCLK:
        ix,iy = x,y
        mouse.append([x,y])

# take image and name it
img = cv2.imread("colo.png",0)
cv2.namedWindow('image')
cv2.setMouseCallback('image',get_location)


while(1):
    cv2.imshow('image',img)
    k = cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        break
    elif k == ord('a'):
        print (ix,iy)
print (mouse)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The answers I am looking for are - (a) how to freeze the frame on a specific frame number and (b) cv2.setMouseCallback('image',get_location) is taking a string as the first argument, how to insert the frame as argument here?

Answer (score 1):

a) use a variable to set the waitKey to 0. Only after a key press the next frame will be shown. Change the variable after "c" is pressed, so the video runs normally:

`waitTime = 0`

```
k = cv2.waitKey(waitTime)
if k == ord('c'):
    waitTime = 20
```

b) the string argument is the name of the window where the callback is attached to. To 'insert the frame', just call `imshow` on the window. The code you have seems fine in that regard.